# Returning an NSTableView's Row Index By Hovering Over It in Swift 4

Tags: swift4, nstableview, mousehover

**I can't seem to figure out a way to return an NSTableView's row index by hovering my mouse over it**. For example, when I hover over a row the index is printed out. Does anyone have any idea on how to achieve this? Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    let items = ["item 1","item 2","item 3","item 4","item 5"]
    
    @IBOutlet var tableView: NSTableView!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // setting up
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

// tableView Data
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        
        return items[row]
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What is the question: how to detect a mouse hover, how to get the mouse location or how to get the row index? Post your code please.

Comment: @Willeke Hope the code I added helps :)

Comment: All really want to know is how to return an NSTableView’s row index by just hovering my mouse over it (hope this makes sense).

Comment: Do you want to detect a hover with a delay or a mouseover? Have you tried anything, where are you stuck?

Comment: Nvm, after tweaking around for a little bit on the code, I finally figured out a way. But thanks for trying :)